# MySQL won't update with a zero as a value

Tags: php, mysql

The user retrieves their product list and i present this list on a page with a textbox prepopulated with quantities. The user can change these quantities and then the form send this data to an update page. I am using the following statement to perform the database update..

```
$sql  = "UPDATE reservations SET quantity=? WHERE tableID= ?";
```

This works perfectly for any value except when the user puts a zero in the textbox and then the update just skips this value and leaves it at the existing one. I have gone directly into the database and can manually change the value to zero with no problem but it just seems to be the web based statement that doesnt work. It was set to INT and i also tried VARCHAR but no luck with either. Any idea what would cause an sql statement to ignore a zero (0) value?

The full update code is

```
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
$sql  = "UPDATE reservations SET quantity=? WHERE tableID= ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST["Quantity"] as $id => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity) $stmt->execute(array($quantity, $id));
}
```

Comment: Please show how you're inserting the parameters to this query.

Comment: Are you using backticks or quotes for the value?  If it is an integer, you don't have to.

Comment: And also give the schema of the table, i.e. `desc reservations`

Comment: SQL shouldn't ignore zero values. The problem is probably with some other part of your code.

Comment: Have you tried putting single quotes on value like this `quantity='0'`?

Comment: Can you edit your original post, rather than put the code in the comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem's right here:

```
if ($quantity) $stmt->execute(array($quantity, $id));
```

0 evaluates to false, so this if statement skips your execute command if `$quantity` is zero.

I don't know why you had this if statement to begin with, but maybe you should replace the condition with `$quantity || $quantity==="0"`.

Comment: `$quantity` will probably be a string so check for `=== "0"`.

Comment: He could even do `if (is_numeric($quantity))`